# Reload php form data after Server side validation

Tags: php

I am doing server side validations for my html values. However when server side validation fails and I return back to the page, the form data is cleared. Is there anyway to do save and reload the form data in php without using any framwork?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the submitted value  (if there is any ) inside your `value=""` like this:

```
$set = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
```

The above is called the ternary operator. And, as I have done it, it will check if someone has already submitted a form with attribute "username"  (`$_POST['username']`) in your form, if yes, then it sets the the value of that form to a variable called `$set` otherwise it just sets it `''` nothing.

Now, all you have to do is just put the `$set` variable inside like: `value=" <?= $set ?> ">`

Answer (score 1):

Well, sure.  Assuming that you're submitting to a different script, and need to be directed back to your page with the form, use [PHP Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).  Save all of the data that you need to reload in the session, and then on your page use the session data to pre-populate the form if it's there.  Once you're done using it (i.e. they've successfully completed their form), then you can clear the session on a subsequent interaction.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Something like $previous_value = isset($_SESSION['refill_previous_value']) ? $_SESSION['refill_previous_value'] : ""; and then <input type="text" name="something" value="<?=$previous_value; ?>">

Comment: The selected answer works so long as the page that displays the form is the same as the one processing it, which is a common, if not ideal, structure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Say you have your input:

```
<input type="text" name="email" />
```

If you did this:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']?>"/>
```

It would repopulate with whatever they typed in.

Answer (score 0):

Send the values to the server using an AJAX call, that wont refresh the page leaving your data intact in the page.